# Seemed vs seems

Tags: tense, perfect-constructions

> 1. Before A.D.900, manuscripts of the Koran (the book containing the teachings of the Islamic religion) **seem to have been** the most common type of book produced and decorated, but after that date a wide range of books were produced for a broad spectrum of patrons.  (TOEFL TPO)

> 2. Before A.D.900, manuscripts of the Koran (the book containing the teachings of the Islamic religion) **seemed to be** the most common type of book produced and decorated, but after that date a wide range of books were produced for a broad spectrum of patrons. (My version)

Which version do you think is better?   Will the other one be frowned upon?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TOEFL version is correct. Yours is not correct.

In this context, "seem" is a verb of intuition or inference. It applies *at the moment someone has that intuition*. We, *today*, can make the inference that manuscripts of the Koran were the most common type of book produced before 900, and after 900 this changed.

If we say "seemed", it means that people in the years before 900 noticed this fact, which is impossible since it includes facts after the year 900.